# Copy selected content form one sheet of notepad++ to another

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a data which is pipe separated ex.

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|
```

I have to copy and paste (to new sheet) only that which is between pipe 6 - 9
I have 10,000 rows like this

how can we do this? How can we write a macro for the same? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I would import the file as CSV into Excel (delimiter splited by pipe), delete columns 1 to 4 and column 10 and save as CSV. For how to Export with pipe as separator see: [Export or Save Excel Files with Pipe (or Other) Delimiters Instead of Commas](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/).

Comment: Thanks Peh...that worked...

Comment: if you have any idea how we can do the same on Notepad++ by using macro

Comment: I would say you can't. A macro in N++ is just a sequence of actions that you can also do manually. See the [N++ documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the entire text into a new buffer then edit the text to remove the unwanted parts. Can do that with a regular expression replace-all of `^(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){5}([^|\r\n]*)\|.*$` with `\1`.

Explanation

```
^                   - start of line
(?:                 - start of a non-capturing group
    [^|\r\n]*       - zero or more characters that are not a | or newlines or carriage returns
    \|              - a |
){5}                - exactly 5 occurences of the previous group
             -- the efect of the above is to match the unwanted leading  characters
([^|\r\n]*)         - a group containing the characters to keep
             -- the wanted part of the line is saved in capture group 1
\|.*$               - a | then everything else to the end of the line
             -- matches the unwanted right-hand part of the line
```

The final `$` is not strictly needed. But, when considered with the opening `^`, it serves to document that the regular expression looks at the whole line.